# How can I save a webcam-recorded mp4 with audio in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, .net, webcam, mp4, video-recording

I'm two days into researching this so I thought I'd post here. It looks like video recording software is usually written in C++ but my project requires C#. It's a WPF application and I just need it to save an mp4 locally. I don't need to upload to a server, I don't need to let the user pick a file location, I don't even need it to display the webcam feed as it's recording. All I need it to do is start/stop recording audio and video from a webcam/microphone and save it in a location that's determined by the code. I understand this may be broken down into steps like connecting to a webcam, connecting to a microphone, synchronizing them, encoding a video file, and saving it on the hard drive.

Are there any .NET classes that can help me with this? If not, can anyone recommend some libraries/frameworks/etc. that handle this sort of thing? I appreciate any help regarding how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Information on the APIs involved, and what you've done so far to try and implement this would be helpful. If assume that whatever this is will just dump the data out to you as some sort of binary stream, in which case the standard `System.IO` libraries should be all you need

Comment: I'm not using any API's at the moment. So far I've tried using avicap32.dll and AForge.NET. Using those I've been able to connect to a webcam and display its images to the screen, but not actually record and save a video.

Comment: Using standard .NET libraries sounds ideal. So which classes do I use? I see a lot of streams and readers and writers in System.IO, but nothing that seems specific to the purpose of recording audio/video.

Comment: Okay, it looks like AForge can save an mp4 just fine, but not with aduio.